# My do/while loop is not working

Tags: java, do-while

So I have a do-while loop that's supposed to read user input. If the user types J then it should ask the user to type in 2 numbers to calculate them but if the user types N then it should stop the loop. Any idea why it isn't working?

```
if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {
    do
    {
        status=true;
    }
    while (status);{
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            status = false;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean status=true;
        while (status){
            Scanner minScanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);  // mina scanners som tar in userinput
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Skriv in ditt nummer en och en :\n"); //obivous

            double nr1 = minScanner1.nextDouble(); // int nr 1 lagrar det userinput skriver in på scanner 1
            double nr2 = minScanner1.nextDouble();


            System.out.println("välj vad du vill göra: ");

            double svar =0;

            String användarInlägg = scanner2.nextLine(); // själva miniräknaren
            if(användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) { 
                svar = nr1 + nr2;
            }
            else if(användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
                svar = nr1 - nr2;
            }
            else if(användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                svar = nr1 * nr2;
            }
            else if(användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
                svar = nr1 / nr2;
            }
            System.out.printf("= %.2f\n ", svar);
            System.out.println("Skriv in J för att fortsätta N för att sluta: \n"); 

            Scanner scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input=scanner3.nextLine();

            do
            {
                if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) status = false;
                else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) status =true;
            } while(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a rest and then get back to your problem

Answer (score 5):

This is not the correct syntax fo do/while loop

it has to be

```
    do {
        // body
    } while(condition);
```

The while loop looks like that

```
    while(condition) {
        // body
    }
```

You have to change your code to something like that:

```
    String input;
    boolean status;
    do {
        input = // read input
        status = input.equalsIgnoreCase("J");
    } while(status);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` structure is this part only:

```
do
{
   status=true;
}
while (status);
```

All the rest don't belong to the `do-while` structure.

BTW, this will be an infinite loop, since the while condition will always be true.

**EDIT**

This might be what you really want:

```
do
{
   //TODO here: update input variable

   if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) status = false;
} while(status);
```

**EDIT2**

```
String input;
do
{
   scanner3 = new Scanner(System.in);
   input=scanner3.nextLine();

   if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) status = false;
} while(status);
```

Comment: Thanks for answere math but its not wroking when i type N the program is still on

Comment: Please post more of your code. You have to update the `input` variable inside the loop.

Comment: Edit 2 not working tryied it :S still when program asks me for J or N and i type J or No nothing happens

Comment: Thanks alot for the help but still same problem this is what i get in the console when i run after typing J or N
 Skriv in J för att fortsätta N för att sluta: 

J
N

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
package com.example.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean status = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (status){
        System.out.println("Skriv in ditt nummer en och en :\n");
        double nr1 = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        double nr2 = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("välj vad du vill göra: ");

        double svr = 0;

        String användarInlägg = sc.nextLine();
        if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("+")) {
            svr = nr1 + nr2;
        } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
            svr = nr1 - nr2;
        } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
            svr = nr1 * nr2;
        } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
            svr = nr1 / nr2;
        }
        System.out.printf("= %.2f\n ", svr);
        System.out
                .println("Skriv in J för att fortsätta N för att sluta: \n");


        String input = sc.nextLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            status = false;
    }
    }

    }
```

you set status to false, if input is "N"

EDIT: put scanner-init out of while

old answer:

its infinite loop, you set status to true but, you iterate as long as status IS true

```
     do
    {
    status=true;
    }
     while (status);
```

actually i posted you a workaround for that problem today on your other question...

Comment: Johny im not sure what 

  do
    {
    status=true;
    }
     while (status);{ means at all

Comment: it is the do-while - loop in YOUR code, everything else is out of the do-while

Comment: @user2764700, ok iput solution for your problem here, just copy the new code and it should work as expected

Comment: just one question it just reboots whenever i type anything else then N, it it possible to do start over if J and stop like it currently is if no? can i just put a Else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
status = true;?

Comment: and you only need 1 scanner:) i guess you should take a look on syntax of do-while - loop

Comment: it doesnt really "reboots" you just execute the code in the while-loop as long as status is true. as soon as you set it to false, while will break on the next status-check and the program will shut down

Comment: Ok , thanks alot for the help johhny read through it and commented it just to remember and understand / once again thanks alot for help to you and rest who helped

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
do
{
       if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {
             status=true;
       }
       else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
           status = false;
       }
}while (status);
```

Comment: trying , nothing happens when i Type J or N

Comment: its still infinite loop, as soon input is "J", as long as he doesnt have another thread or smt...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is:

```
 do{
    status=true;
 } while (status);
```

The `if` clause is never reached. You need to put that `if`clause inside the loop.